# How to connect to Oracle database and run a query through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, excel-2016

I have a master sheet 1 in which a VB script runs and filters some records. In  sheet 2, I want to have a query which will be open ended as I want it to pick an ID from the Sheet 1. The result can be saved in the same sheet or a different sheet. 
Since there are multiple rows in Sheet 1 after filtering, the query has to run in loop and each time, the new result based on the next ID should replace the old result.

So please help me with two processes,
1. How to connect to oracle DB?
2. Where to put the query and how to execute it?

PS: I have MS Excel 2016 32-bit.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You might wanna follow this (http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/oracle-connection-string-in-vba/)

Comment: @Gareth I tried this
Data tab > Get Data > From Database > From Oracle Database > Then I gave my Database service name in the text field > A navigator opens with all the available tables. After I select the required tab, I am clicking on "Load To" option. A new pop-up appears, with four options - Table only, Pivot Table, Pivot chart, Connection only. Here, there is a properties option, which is disabled. I am selecting connection only. 
Now, if I click on "Existing Connections" option in Data tab, I am seeing the table as a query and not as a connection.

Comment: @Mikku I am getting "User-defined type not defined" error in line 2. I am using service name